# VS Code is showing weird numbers before the output? How to fix this?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When running my code in VS Code, it is showing a random weird number in the output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a;
  printf("Enter a no: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  if (a%2==0) {
    printf("%d It is even no");
  }
  else{
    printf("%d It is odd no");
  }
}
```

[image: Vscode random weird number shown in output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That's not VS Code's fault. _That's from your code_. VS Code is just running your code and that output is from your code. I haven't done C for a long time but I'm pretty sure it's from the `printf` with a `%d` at the start.

Comment: because of `%d` it expects an argument after the format string

Answer (score 0):

As Gino's said, the problem is that you have a %d at the beginning of each of your printf() calls. This tells printf() to pull a number from its argument list. Since you didn't provide a number in the argument list, it pulls the next number on the stack, whatever that happens to be. It's probably a local variable.